# Xamarin iOS Push Notifications stopped working after minor changes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been following [this documentation](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseioscloudmessaging) and I’ve been testing iOS push notifications from Firebase.

Initially, my problem was that when I sent a notification from the Firebase console to iOS, the ApplicationReceivedRemoteMessage method was being called instead of the DidReceiveRemoteNotification method.

However, after adding some changes, to the code, I noticed that after sending notifications from Firebase I am not calling ApplicationReceivedRemoteMessage, DidReceiveRemoteNotification or any of the other methods in AppDelegate.cs

Looking at my changesets, I can see that I’ve only modified the info.plist to submit the app to the app store and added a new image.

What can I do to try and get Xamarin iOS push notifications working again?

Comment: What did you modify in the info.plist? (The Bundle id?)

Comment: I modified the **CFBundleIdentifier,** I removed the file extension from the value of **UILaunchStoryboardName** and I added a new string to the **CFBundleIconFiles** array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...I modified the CFBundleIdentifier...

Since you changed the Bundle Identifier it no longer matches your Firebase app.

Example:

[image]

This value can not be changed once the app is added in the Firebase Console so you will need to **`Add App`**  to add a new iOS application with the correct Bundle ID and you can delete the old one.

**Note:** This also changes the `GoogleService-Info.plist` so you will need to download the new one and replace the one that currently exists in your app.

Comment: Thanks. I added a new app and updated the plist file. Now I can get the FCM token, but I'm having trouble sending push notifications. From Firebase, if I only send to the one device with a specific FCM registration token, I can send the notification, but I cannot send the notification if I target a user segment. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: @JuanPaoloDelaCruz I'm assuming you are calling `SubscribeToTopic` and using that topic in in the Firebase console? But you should post a new question since that is a different subject then your original question. Accept this one since it solved your initial problem.

Comment: I'm not calling SubscribeToTopic as I was just trying to send to all iOS devices using Target > UserSegment from the Firebase console. But you're right; I'll post a new question for that.